# Convert a numpy array into an array of signs with 0 as positive

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large numpy array with positive data, negative data and 0s. I want to convert it to an array with the signs of the current values such that 0 is considered positive. If I use `numpy.sign` it returns 0 if the current value is 0 but I want something that returns 1 instead. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: `2*(x >= 0).astype(int) - 1`

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a lot! I didn't know pyhton had logical indexing.

Comment: OK, I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x` is the array, you could use `2*(x >= 0) - 1`.

`x >= 0` will be an array of boolean values (i.e. `False` and `True`), but when you do arithmetic with it, it is effectively cast to an array of 0s and 1s.

You could also do `np.sign(x) + (x == 0)`.  (Note that `np.sign(x)` returns floating point values, even when `x` is an integer array.)